# Possible mistake in Peskin and Schroeder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, textbook-erratum

Attached here is a picture from Peskin and Schroeder, page 342, section 10.5.

[image]

If I understand it correctly, the "shifted momentum variable" $l$ should be equal to ($k$ + independent of $k$ part). In this regard, the coefficients of $k^2$ (in the denominator) and $l$ in Eqs. 10.57 and 10.58 should be the same, which they are not. Moreover, even the coefficient of $m^2$ is +1 and not -1. Can someone either confirm or debunk my argument? Because this leads to a change in the sign in Eq 10.59 from $y(1-y)p^2 \to y(1+y)p^2$.

PS: As I understand, $P^2$ is supposed to be a function independent of $k$ (and possibly m as well), though it can depend on $p_3$ and $p \equiv p_1 + p_2$.

Comment: What edition are you reading? My1995 edition has $-[(1-w)+ w x(1-x)] \ell^2 - P^2 + m^2$ for (10.58)

Comment: It's also 1995 by Addison Wesley. However, my copy might have a misprint, because your expression matches my conclusion.

Comment: Peskin keeps a very thorough errata on his website, you should always look for these first when you think you've caught an error because they aren't particularly rare: https://www.slac.stanford.edu/~mpeskin/QFTtype.html